Block Nautilus at startup
I created a program in QT to run RDP sessions. The user must have access only to this program that runs at startup, nothing else. All I need is a desktop and an icon bar. I've already done this with raspberry OS but would like to do it on Ubuntu.
With Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
I created two users. I wish for one it didn't load Nautilus on startup. How can I do?

It may help to know why?

I want to create a limited session where the user cannot interact with the file manager

Again I ask why? Is there files or directories you do not want them to use? Please edit the question and add the info there.

There are countless ways to interact with the file system. Besides command line (shell) most applications are potential file managers. The only logical way to constrain users is through permissions and ACLs.
